# Several ToolTip texts are shown when using MouseOver event

Tags: c#, tooltip

I've got a form with a combo to pick up a customer and a button. 
When a customer is selected and you move the mouse over the button a ToolTip is shown with information about this customer.

I have customized the tooltip using ToolTip_Draw.

All of these works fine.

The problem is that when I change de selected customer and then move the mouse over the button several ToolTip texts are shown. One for each customer I've previously selected.

I've tried to somehow empty de ToolTip but nothing seems to work.

```
private void bttCitas_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string mSQL = @"    SELECT one, two, three
            FROM customers
            WHERE id = " + comboCliente.SelectedValue + ";";
    DataTable tablaTemp = retrieveData(mSQL);

    string customerText = ConvertDataTableToString(tablaTemp);
    System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip Emergente = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
    Emergente.OwnerDraw = true; 
    Emergente.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(ToolTip_Draw);
    Emergente.AutoPopDelay = 150000;
    Emergente.InitialDelay = 500;
    Emergente.ReshowDelay = 500;
    Emergente.SetToolTip(this.bttCitas, customerText);            
}


void ToolTip_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    using (e.Graphics)
    {
        Font f = new Font("Courier New", 9.0f);
        e.DrawBackground();

        e.DrawBorder();
        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(GLOBALToolTipFontColor);                
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, f, myBrush, new PointF(2, 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: While I cannot pinpoint the cause, I would certainly move the tooltip creation to an event that happens less frequently than mouse_hover; probably to the code where you update the customer. This way, each time you are passing the mouse over the button you are doing a full DB, only to retrieve the same info again and again, and creating more instances of tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured out what happens.

I need to declare Emergente out of the MouseOver event and then dispose it in the MouseLeave:

```
private ToolTip Emergente; 

private void bttCitas_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string mSQL = @"    SELECT one, two, three
            FROM customers
            WHERE id = " + comboCliente.SelectedValue + ";";
    DataTable tablaTemp = retrieveData(mSQL);

    string customerText = ConvertDataTableToString(tablaTemp);
    Emergente = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
    Emergente.OwnerDraw = true; 
    Emergente.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(ToolTip_Draw);
    Emergente.AutoPopDelay = 150000;
    Emergente.InitialDelay = 500;
    Emergente.ReshowDelay = 500;
    Emergente.SetToolTip(this.bttCitas, customerText);            
}


void ToolTip_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    using (e.Graphics)
    {
        Font f = new Font("Courier New", 9.0f);
        e.DrawBackground();

        e.DrawBorder();
        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(GLOBALToolTipFontColor);                
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, f, myBrush, new PointF(2, 2));
    }
}


private void bttCitas_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Emergente.Dispose(); 
}
```